# How To generate unique ID for controls inside a User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, user-controls

I have a User Control in which I have one label.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblProductionName" 
           runat="server" 
           Text="Production Name will come here">
</asp:Label>
```

I render the given UC from code behind using this function:

```
private string RenderControl(Control control)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    control.RenderControl(writer);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

After rendering, I get this as the output string:

```
<span id="lblProductionName">Production Name will come here</span>
```

Now, when I put two instances of the same User Control, I get the same span ID in the output string.

I want to generate two different IDs for two instances of User Control. How can I generate it?

Comment: Why do you render the html manually instead of loading the `UserControl` programmatically and add it to the page (or even simply add them declaratively on the aspx)?

Comment: I gotta go with @TimSchmelter here. If you just add controls to it via the `Controls.Add` method, and get rid of the `RenderControl` method and just set the appropriate properties or leverage `Attributes.Add` if necessary - you'll get rid of the issue with the `id` because it will leverage the naming container.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I'm developing a web form generator application in which user can design its own web form,in this application user is dynamically adding components(a component may have more than one occurrence) to an editor,from that editor i get a HTML. Now  I read all HTML and according to the components in that HTML, I render the corresponding User Control(s) and after rendering it, I finally get a HTML(in string format) which i finally provide to a div from code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, int> controlInstances = new Dictionary<string, int>();

private string RenderControl(Control control)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    int index = GetOrAddControlInstanceCount(control);

    control.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
    control.ID = control.GetType().Name + index;

    control.RenderControl(writer);

    return sb.ToString();
}

private int GetOrAddControlInstanceCount(Control control)
{
    string key = control.GetType().Name;

    if (!controlInstances.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        controlInstances.Add(key, 0);
    }

    return controlInstances[key]++;
}
```

More advanced solution would be maybe to use a [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The option which always works would be: Guid.NewGuid :)

Comment: Answer not related to the question.

Comment: @SidM How not? How To generate unique ID for controls inside a User Control... Guid.NewGuid would generate unique value

Comment: @alex : That one liner answer is not at all helpful, a working code might help.